# Is there a way to put the grid in the center

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm creating a fake site for Pentel and I want to insert images of pens using a grid layout. However, the grid shifts to the left and a scroll bar appears in the bottom of the page.

Full Screen:

[image]

Small Screen:
[image]

I want to make it so the scroll bar disappears and the grid is in the center.

HTML:

```
<div class="pens-images-container">
        <div class="pens-images">
          <img src="./images/black-energel-rtx-refillable-liquid-gel-pen.png" alt="black EnerGel RTX refillable liquid gel pen">
          <img src="./images/blue-ballpoint-07-clear-barrel.png" alt="blue ballpoint 0.7 clear barell pen">
          <img src="./images/EnerGel-X-retractable-gel-pen.png" alt="EnerGel-X retractable gel pen">
          <img src="./images/tradio-fountaion-blue-ink-white-barrel-pen.png" alt="tradio fountain blue ink white barrel pen">
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f5dc;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100vw;
}

.pens-images-container {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.pens-images {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2em;
  
}

.pens-images img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;

}
```

Comment: like so, with `margin: auto` ? https://jsfiddle.net/59df1bgq/2/

Answer (score 0):

According to me, there is a problem in you css code.
In your given lines of code:

```
.wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100vw;
}    
.pens-images-container {
      margin-top: 2rem;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
```

Just remove the line `width: 100vw;` and check. Instead of this you can write `width: 100%;` It may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The image being on the left is caused by the wrapping div being wider, than the image, so you have to center the image inside the div, too:

The horizontal scrollsbars might be caused by the `100vw`, if there is padding or margin applied on the wrapping elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/59df1bgq/31/

I have taken the freedom and replaced all images by placeholders with the dimension of 400*400 pixels.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f5dc;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.pens-images-container {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.pens-images {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 70%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2em;
}

.pens-images img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="pens-images-container">
        <div class="pens-images">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="black EnerGel RTX refillable liquid gel pen">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="blue ballpoint 0.7 clear barell pen">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="EnerGel-X retractable gel pen">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="tradio fountain blue ink white barrel pen">
        </div>
</div>
```